# Infinite carousel with variable items

Tags: jquery, carousel

I’m trying to create carousel component similar to [this one](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/), and basically this implementation is what I’m looking for, but what it doesn’t handle (or doesn’t have as an option) is slides with variable number of items in them.

What I’m talking about is this: implementation mentioned in link works with 3 items in each slide, and if last slide doesn’t have exactly 3 items, it fills that slot with empty item. Which is reasonably good way of making infinite implemenation easy.

I tried to modify it to fill that empty slot with first item in list if only one slot is empty, first two items if two slots are empty, etc. but I stumbled on problem where next set of slides has completely different display and logic and therefore animation becomes "glitchy"—e.g. going back to "start" first slide would have second, third and fourth item without first item if only one slot in last slide is empty.

My current "workaraound" is cloning, appending and prepending items on every reposition (clicking of controls buttons), but this is highly non-performant (manipulating DOM every time and caching new set of elements based on original selector can be costly) and probably "lazy way out".

Is there any clever solution for this problem?

Comment: have you try to "play" with position absolute to reorder elements ? or maybe jquery.detach instead of cloning ?

Comment: Actually, I didn’t clone elements, I detached them to keep original references, but this basically works the same way.

Comment: what about my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i just try done this, with position:absolute; way

seem work fine, just adapt anim to your need

here was my logic

```
overflow:hidden; position:relative;
```

on the container

all element get

```
position:absolute;
```

all are hidden but the 3 to show, this 3 element get left position hard set to their index (from draw element)

```
left:(4+n*40)+"px"
```

i set an array with index of current elements

var current = [0,1,2];

on change i just put +3 or -3 to this array content, with a modulo to limit in the good range

```
function getIndex(n)
{    if(n < 0) return nbelem+n;
     return n%nbelem;
}
```

an util function will take current array and give me the new array with new elements to show

```
function getNewIndex(n)
{   var newIndex = [];
    for(c=0;c<3;c++)
        newIndex[c] = getIndex(current[c]+n);
    return newIndex;
}
```

on change i get the new current elements visible and their positions to the right or left of the container limit, after that i animate them to their new positions ( left:(4+n*40)+"px" ) and animate the old showed elements to the left or right container limits before hide them

for do all this anims i write a tiny dedicated function, showMeElems(newArray,animWay)

and i just need to define left and right click to use this function

```
$left.click(function(){
    showMeElems(getNewIndex(-3),"left");
});

$right.click(function(){
    showMeElems(getNewIndex(3),"right");
})
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/SbNJR/)

good luck

Comment: In the mean time, I’ve modified my original solution to work slightly better, but your way seems to be a somewhat tricky solution :). I will try it next time if there will be the same problem to solve. Thanks!